# Difference between Involve in, participate in, take part in, and doing something

Tags: phrase-meaning

My former teacher had been teaching biology and on her own doing research in related field  for ten years.
I wonder if the following sentences have the same meaning as the above sentence:
My former teacher had been involving in biology and related research for ten years.
My former teacher had been participating in biology and related research for ten years.
My former teacher had been taking part in biology and related research for ten years.

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason for using past perfect, *don't*. A natural phrasing might be *My former teacher **was involved** in biology and related research for ten years* (you could use ***took part in*** or ***participated in***, there's nothing much to choose between any of them).

Comment: Thank you FumbleFingers. I can't work out the difference between "be involved in" and "involve in".

Comment: Syntactically, *to **be involved** in [something]* is like *to **be interested** in it*. Compare with, say, *to be **happy** with it*, and note that ***involved, interested, happy*** are all effectively *adjectival* usages. You can't say *"I involved in research"* for the same reason you can't say *"I happy in my job"*. Neither of them include a true "verb" - you need something like *I **am** involved, he **seems** interested, she **feels** happy*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples, the use of "had been" leads me to ask "and then what?"

> She *had been* doing X for 10 years [but now is doing Y].

If that's the intent, then your examples are missing the follow-on "Y".

If instead you only want to state a fact about her 10yrs in biology & leave it at that, then @FumbleFingers' comment above provides a correct usage:

> (participated, took part, was involved).

As to the difference between verbs, there isn't much of one.
To participate, to be involved (in/with), or to take part (in) are all essentially the same in this case.

The only note I'd make is your use of "involving" above, which is incorrect. 
It should be "had been involved in..."